# How to use ReactJs with just Babel without webpack or other blunderer?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs, babel-cli

I am trying to create an environment for ReactJs using just babel and its presets and plugins.
So far I can render my React component using transform-react-jsx plugin. But I can't add CSS to it. How do I do it?
`

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "es2017", "react"],
    "plugins": ["transform-runtime", "transform-async-to-generator", 
    "transform-react-jsx"]
}
```

`

This is how my .babelrc looks like. I have an express server what sends an index.html rendering my React component. It's more of serverside rendering though using react-dom/server. I am cool with anything as long as I get to create react components with CSS just using babel.

Comment: Maybe this can be of help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36511100/how-do-i-use-react-js-without-a-bundler