# how is JSX related code in React get interpreted?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html shows that the code below is a valid declaration. This code is not a normal javascript code. How does it get interpreted? What is the steps in between that I miss?

```
const element = <h1> Hello, world!</h1>;
```

Comment: The article you link explains exactly how, with several examples showing JSX with plain JS equivalents. Or read the several other articles on that site about JSX, like https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

Comment: To be fair, the original article really doesn't explain clearly that JSX can't be used in a browser without a compilation step, does it?  In fact it says 'JSX may remind you of a template language, but it comes with the full power of JavaScript', which might confuse you into thinking you can use JSX like JavaScript, without Babel or another compiler.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this lies here https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

As mentioned, it is just "syntactic sugar" for `React.createElement`. The jsx gets compiled to `React.createElement`

Eg: `<h1>Hello, world!</h1>` gets compiled to:

```
React.createElement("h1", null, "Hello, world!")
```

Here's the [babel online compiler](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?presets=react&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwKYBt1wBQEpEDeAUIogE6pQhlIA8AJjAG4B8AEhlogO5xnr0AhLQD0jVgG4iAXyJA) to see what jsx compiles to in javascript. You can use this to play around.

Answer (score 1):

You are of course right that `const element = <h1> Hello, world!</h1>;` is not normal JavaScript, and it won't work if you simply put it in `<script>` tags in an HTML page (but see below).

As a result to get it to work it has to be compiled to JavaScript.  There are several compilers that will do this, the most widely-used being [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) which has a [plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx) that does it.  The [TypeScript compiler will also compile this syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html) if you set the right flags, which means you don't have to worry about another compiler if you are using TypeScript.

You can use [Babel from the command line](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli) to compile a script with JSX to another script which is proper JavaScript.  There's an [online compiler](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?presets=react&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwKYBt1wBQEpEDeAUIogE6pQhlIA8AJjAG4B8AEhlogO5xnr0AhLQD0jVgG4iAXyJA).  More practically, if you're using a module bundler like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) then there's a [plug-in](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/) that will do it for you.  You can even [compile from script tags in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46584926/4166522) if you include the right libraries and tell the browser this isn't JavaScript with `<script type="text/babel" >`.

The most common approach is to do this via a module bundler, I suspect, although configuring that isn't particularly easy.  As an aside, if you're on Windows and use Visual Studio I have recently uploaded a [project template that does the configuration in a very simple project](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Rich-Newman.ReactJavaScriptHTMLApplicationTemplate) for you.

As other answers here have noted, Babel compiles the JSX to JavaScript, but by default it compiles it to JavaScript that makes calls to functions that are included in the React libraries such as React.createComponent.  This means the React libraries also have to be available, either via a  tag or by importing/requiring them if you are configured to use npm modules.  Having said that, the React team have recently provided a way to [use JSX without importing the whole of React](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html).

Answer (score 0):

`<h1> Hello, world!</h1>` is converted to following javascript using babel

```
const element = React.createElement("h1", null, " Hello, world!");
```